# Running ApexClasses in PE with Security Review and Certification

Tags: apex, managed-package, professional-edition, security-review

I've a managed package which I would like to be installed in a Professional Edition.

When I try to install the package in the PE, I get following error, of course my package has few ApexClasses/Pages/ControllerExtensions etc and does HttpCallouts to a third party WS.

> Installing this package requires the following feature and its
>   associated permissions: Apex Classes

I came across a post somewhere stating that this error would go away if I get my package "Security reviewed and Certified", which seems to be a lenthy process BTW, but not too sure about this.

My question is, does "Security review and Certification" allow me to install the same package in the PE?
Or are PEs missing ApexClasses altogether, i.e my package can only be installed in Enterprise/Unlimited editions.

**EDIT: While having the security certification does allow installation of the app in PE, I've come across certain PEs (of existing customers) on which installation fails with the same error.**

**Are there any conditions related to PEs which could restrict installing even a review passed application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm

The document above i pulled from salesforce itself and it clearly says that if authorized your managed package(ISV) app can run apex .Again there are conditions like if you are exposing apex as  SOAP webservice  it will fail.Only REST is allowed.

callouts are allowed if app is authorized.So if apps are authorized then you should be good .Also check you have permission to run the apex in your profile .

Comment: please check my edit.